# Onmouseover sound in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using the following script for onmouseover sound effects on menu buttons on a site.

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--


var aySound = new Array();

aySound[0] = "s.mp3";

document.write('<BGSOUND ID="auIEContainer">')
IE = (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1 && document.all)? 1:0;
NS = (navigator.appName=="Netscape" && navigator.plugins["LiveAudio"])? 1:0;
ver4 = IE||NS? 1:0;
onload=auPreload;

function auPreload() {
if (!ver4) return;
if (NS) auEmb = new Layer(0,window);
else {
Str = "<DIV ID='auEmb' STYLE='position:absolute;'></DIV>";
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("BeforeEnd",Str);
}
var Str = '';
for (i=0;i<aySound.length;i++)
Str += "<EMBED SRC='"+aySound[i]+"' AUTOSTART='FALSE' HIDDEN='TRUE'>"
if (IE) auEmb.innerHTML = Str;
else {
auEmb.document.open();
auEmb.document.write(Str);
auEmb.document.close();
}
auCon = IE? document.all.auIEContainer:auEmb;
auCon.control = auCtrl;
}
function auCtrl(whSound,play) {
if (IE) this.src = play? aySound[whSound]:'';
else eval("this.document.embeds[whSound]." + (play? "play()":"stop()"))
}
function playSound(whSound) { if (window.auCon) auCon.control(whSound,true); }
function stopSound(whSound) { if (window.auCon) auCon.control(whSound,false); }
//-->
</script>
```

This works fine in IE but not Firefox.

**Does anybody know if there is way to have the same onmouseover sound effect in both IE and Firefox without using flash?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **only** way for sound on your website is to use either flash or whatever Facebook uses for incoming IM, but that too requires Apple Quicktime to play.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know if there is way to have the same `onmouseover` sound effect in both IE and Firefox without using Flash?

Well, you could use a JavaScript library which normalizes cross-browser `onmouseover` behaviors. Or, if you really don’t want to — it should be possible in plain ol’ JavaScript, with a lot of hacks to support all different browsers. Your choice.

As posted in [gist 243946](http://gist.github.com/243946), here’s a jQuery snippet to do exactly what you want:

```
var $sound = $('<div id="sound" />').appendTo('body');
$('#special-links-that-play-annoying-sounds-when-hovered a').hover(function() {
 $sound.html('<embed src="foo.mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false">');
}, function() {
 // We could empty the innerHTML of $sound here, but that would only slow things down.
});
```

Of course, this could be written in plain old JavaScript (without jQuery) as well.